# Function pointer as template argument and signature

Tags: c++, templates, lua, function-pointers

Can I pass a "general" function pointer as an template argument with it's signature? I know that I can pass the function signature to a template:

```
template<typename signature>
struct wrapper;

template<typename RT, typename... ATs>
struct wrapper<RT (ATs...)> {};

int f(int, double)

wrapper<decltype(f)> w;
```

I also can pass an function pointer as a non-type template argument:

```
   template<int (*pF)(int, double)> myTemp() {
      pf(1, 1.0);
   }

   myTemp<f>();
```

What I would like to do is something like this

```
   template<typename RT (*pF)(typename ATs...)>
```

Is this possible? The function pointer must be passed as a template argument and must not be passed as a function parameter.

---

I want to use the template to wrap c functions and make them callable from lua. The following code works (c++14, gcc, lua-5.3), but could be improved.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

extern "C"  {
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
}

using namespace std;

int add(int i, int j) {
    cout << "adding " << i << " to " << j << "." << endl;
    return i + j;
}

int sub(int i, int j) {
    cout << "subtracting " << j << " from " << i << "." << endl;
    return i - j;
}

// ****************************

template<typename signature>
struct wrapper;

template<typename RT, typename... ATs>
struct wrapper<RT (ATs...)> {

    template<RT (*pF)(ATs...)>
    void reg(lua_State *L, const char*n) {
        auto lw = [](lua_State *L) -> RT {
            lua_pushnumber(L, call<0>(pF, L));
            return 1;
        };
        lua_pushcfunction(L, lw);
        lua_setglobal(L, n);
    }

    template<int i, typename... ETs>
    static
    typename std::enable_if<i != sizeof...(ATs), RT>::type
    call(RT (*f)(ATs...), lua_State *L, ETs... Es) {
        auto arg = lua_tonumber(L, i+1);
        return call<i+1>(f, L, Es..., arg);
    }

    template<int i, typename... ETs>
    static
    typename std::enable_if<i == sizeof...(ATs), RT>::type
    call(RT (*f)(ATs...), lua_State *L, ETs... Es) {
        return f(Es...);
    }

};

#define regLua(L, fct, str) wrapper<decltype(fct)>().reg<fct>(L, str)

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    luaL_dostring(L, "print(\"Hello World!\")");

    // Ugly: add must be passed two times! Not a very userfriendly syntax.
    wrapper<decltype(add)>().reg<add>(L, "add");
    // Looks better, but uses a macro...
    regLua(L, sub, "sub");
    // optimal (but possible??):
    // wrap<sub>(L, "sub");

    luaL_dostring(L, "print(\"add:\", add(3, 5))");
    luaL_dostring(L, "print(\"sub:\", sub(3, 5))");

    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I read [_function pointer as template argument_](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5Dfunction+pointer+as+template+parameter) about five to seven times a week (if not more frequently) here. Sure you cannot find any primary information, which is already available?

Comment: I didn't got what `myTemp()` is supposed to be. Maybe you miss a return type?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I searched for function pointer as template argument, but all I found are the first two cases, and not the third in which I'm interested. If you have a link concerning this case, I would be gratefull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

c++17 allows:

```
template <auto value> struct wrapper;
```

and then your specialization

```
template<typename RT, typename... ATs, RT (*pF)(ATs...)>
struct wrapper<pF> {
    static void reg(lua_State *L, const char* n) {
        auto lw = [](lua_State *L) {
            lua_pushnumber(L, call(L, std::index_sequence_for<ATS...>()));
            return 1;
        };
        lua_pushcfunction(L, lw);
        lua_setglobal(L, n);
    }

    template<std::size_t ... Is>
    static
    RT call(lua_State *L, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return pF(lua_tonumber(L, 1 + Is)...);
    }
};
```

And usage:

```
wrapper<&add>::reg(L, "add");
```

Before c++17, your `wrapper` has to be

```
template <typename Sig, sig Pf> struct wrapper;

template<typename RT, typename... ATs, RT (*pF)(ATs...)>
struct wrapper<Rt (*)(ATS...), pF> {
    // Code
};
```

which forces you to repeat the function name (if you don't manually type its signature)

```
wrapper<decltype(&add), &add>::reg(L, "add");
```

Comment: Anyway the question has not the _c1z_ tag, so I guess this doesn't really answer it. Am I wrong?

Comment: @skypjack: pre-c++1z, that syntax is not supported, so to really answer to OP's question, no it is not possible to use similar syntax.

Comment: Well, that one (_no, it is not possible_) would be a response indeed. Then, adding information about the upcoming features enriches the answer, of course. :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you very much. This answers my question. I will try if the c++17 syntax is already available with my compiler version.